# Join with external csv files in psql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a list of IDs in an external csv file and I would like to query rows with the corresponding IDs in a table in the database. Instead of copy the csv into the database and then join, is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: 1. You can bring the data into your database and perform the merge. 2. You can bring the database outside and do a join/merge (like on a pandas dataframe) 3. You can use something like [file_fdw module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) to turn our csv into a "foreign table" and use it in a join/query.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks. The table in the database from which I want to query is huge. I guess the easiest way is still bringing the external csv into the database. But I will try the foreign table way.